# In the Correspondence Theorem, does the modulo subgroup need to be the kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Let $f: G \twoheadrightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $K$. If $S$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $K$, and $S^*=\{f(x) \in H \mid x \in S\}$, then $S/K \cong S^*$. This is how my book states the Correspondence Theorem.  However, no other sources say that $K$ must be the kernel of $f$. Other sources just say that $K \vartriangleleft G$ and $K \subset S$.

What is going on here? Does $K$ need to be the kernel, or just a normal subgroup contained in $S$?

Comment: Dead giveaway: a subgroup is normal iff it is the kernel of some homomorphism.

Comment: @Uzman That's true, but I believe the OP is asking whether the correspondence theorem works if we consider $G/N$, where $N$ is any normal subgroup, rather than $\ker f$.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if it holds for any normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, where $N \subset S$.

Comment: Isn't $f$ arbitrary for the correspondence theorem? Either we fix $N$ or $f$ to talk about the correspondence, no?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you elaborate please

Comment: I am assuming we fix $f$

Comment: Well, fixing $f$ is precisely fixing a normal subgroup $N$, so is the correspondence between the two narratives of the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $K$ must be the kernel of $f$.

But, to be clear, this isn't really a restriction.  When talking about the quotient group $G/K$, where $K$ is any normal subgroup, there is a natural map $f\colon G \to G/K$ defined by $x \mapsto xK$.  This map is a surjective homomorphism and it's kernel is exactly $K$!

So in one sense you could say that in the correspondence theorem you choose $f$ and then the subgroup $K$ must be the kernel of $f$.  But in another sense you could say that you choose $K$ and then the map $f$ is, up to isomorphism, just the unique surjective map with kernel $K$.  So $f$ and $K$ have to "match up" in the end, but this isn't a restriction.  You can choose either and then the other is determined uniquely (up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick a concrete example. We'll use $G = D_8$, the dihedral group with $8$ elements, and let's use the homomorphism $f: G \to (\{\pm1\}, \times)$ which sends rotations to $1$, and reflections to $-1$.

So, let's just let all of $G$ be our subgroup containing $\ker f$,the set of rotations; we'll let $S = G$.

Thus, $S^* = \{f(x) \in H : x \in S\} = \{\pm 1\}$. Then we do indeed have $G/\ker f \cong S^*$.

Now, if instead of modding by $\ker f$, we choose the normal subgroup  $\{1, r^2\}$, then it's clear that $G/\{1, r^2\}$ is too big to be isomorphic to $S^*$; the quotient group having $4$ elements but $S*$ only having two.

The correspondence theorem really does require us to look at $S/\ker f$ when we're $f$ to define using $S^* = \{f(x) \in H : x \in S\}$.